# Laravel Blade If Condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have some button in my blade view, and I want to use if statement like:

if subject id is equal to auth user or role is admin then the button must be visible else hide that button.

I have already implemented the relationship both in my table and model, but I don't know how to construct the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if($subject_id == auth()->user || user()->hasRole("admin") )

button here

@endif
```

try this code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@if($subject_id == auth()->user)

button here

@endif
```

Comment: how bout the role sir? i want admin will have this button